# httacces Rewrite URLs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wanted to rewrite some urls from

www.example.ro/women_shoes.php to www.example.ro/women-shoes/
and with pagination looks like
www.example.ro/women_shoes.php?page=1 to www.example.ro/women_shoes/pagina-2/

www.example.ro/men_shoes.php to www.example.ro/men-shoes/
with pagination like the first one

www.example.ro/sandale_barbati.php to www.example.ro/sandale-barbati/
and so on..

for the last example  i tryed

```
RewriteRule ^sandale-barbati/pagina-([0-9]+)/ /sandale-barbati.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^sandale-barbati/?$ /sandale_barbati.php?$
```

but i need to write that for every page...
is there a way to do that automaticaly for all pages ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always use the same naming for all your pages, this will work:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)([-_]){1}([a-zA-Z]+)/pagina-([0-9]+)/$ $1_$3.php?page=$4
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)([-_]){1}([a-zA-Z]+)/$ $1_$3.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)/pagina-([0-9]+)/$ /$1.php?page=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)/$ /$1.php

You can surf to /women_shoes/ and it will be the /women_shoes.php page.
You can surf to /women-shoes/ and it will be the /women_shoes.php page.
You can surf to the /shoes/ and it will be the /shoes.php page.
```

I hope this has met all your requirements and was of sufficient help to you. For future reference, the website http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is very handy when dealing with RegEx (such as .htaccess rewrite rules).

Comment: Nope, still 404 error not found... it seems that for pagest like... example.ro/noutati.php it works.. but not at all with the pagination.. with the pages that has 2 words in it like.. women_shoes.. dosen`t work at all

Comment: Did you make sure that the getter has the same name as expected?
Are the php files you want to access in the root folder?
Are there any other rewrite rules in your htaccess?

Comment: yes, i made all the pages from /women_shoes.php to women-shoes/ not women_shoes/... it will be hard for me now to change all again to women_shoes/ it`s there a posibility to maintain my format women-shoes/ .. sorry i made you lose some time for me